# Elasticsearch: casting doubles to geo_point. Error with invalid geohash character

Tags: elasticsearch, geopoints

I'm getting an error when I run this script to concatenate longitude and latitude doubles into a geo_point.

```
ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[the character \'.\' is not a valid geohash character]
```

Here's my script for reference:

```
mappings: {
    'index': {
           'transform': {
                   'lang': 'groovy',
                            'script': "ctx._source['coords'] = [ctx._source['lon'],ctx._source['lat']]"
            }
            'properties': {
                    'lon': {
                            'type': 'double',
                    },
                    'lat': {
                            'type': 'string',
                    },
                    'coords': {
                            'type': 'geo_point',
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are extracting data from the source, you need to transform strings in to doubles in your groovy script:

```
new Double(ctx._source['lon']);
```

Comment: thanks! that worked--I wrote it in line so I ended up doing ctx._source['lon'].toDouble()

Will this script run every time I query on coords?